# create dynamic events for a vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem with vue routes. I am using laravel 6 with vue@2.6.10

I want to create the actions button in the header dynamically (the actions are different which depends on the component). This AppHeader component is on every component and on the current component I want to create in the header the events for the current component.

For example the component CategoryDetails I  want to have two actions in the header (save and exit).

The route foe the category is this:

```
        path: '/',
        redirect: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardLayout,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/categories',
                component: Category,
                name: 'category',
                meta: {
                    requiresAuth: true
                }
            },
            {
                path: '/categories/:CategoryID',
                component: CategoryDetails,
                name: 'category-details',
                props: true,
                meta: {
                    requiresAuth: true
                }
            },
        ]
```

In the component CategoryDetails:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header :actions="actions"></app-header> 
        // other code
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import AppHeader from "../../layout/AppHeader";
    export default {
        name: "CategoryDetails",
        components: {AppHeader},
        data() {
            actions: [{label: 'Save', event: 'category.save'}, {label: 'Exit', event: 'category.exit'}],
        },
        mounted() {
            const vm = this;
            Event.$on('category.save', function(){
                alert('Save Category!');
            });
            Event.$on('category.exit', function(){
                vm.$router.push({name: 'category'});
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

I crated the action object which tells the header component what events to emit and listen to them in this component.

In the AppHeader component:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="typeof(actions) !== 'undefined'" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 text-right">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-neutral" v-for="btn in actions" @click="onActionClick(btn.event)">{{ btn.label }}</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "AppHeader",    
    props: [
        'actions'
    ],
    methods: {
        onActionClick(event) {
            Event.$emit(event);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The Event is the "bus event" defined in the app.js

```
/**
 * Global Event Listener
 */

window.Event = new Vue();
```

So... let`s tested :)

I am in the category component. Click on the category details ... the actions are in the header (save and exit). Click on exit...we area pushed back to the category component... click again to go in the category details and click save ... the alert appears TWICE.

Exit and enter again ... the alert "Save Category!" appears 3 times.....and so on ...

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/component-not-destroying/25008/10

I have to destroy the "zombie effect"

```
destroyed() {
    Event.$off('category.save');
    Event.$off('category.exit');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not with your routes. I don't know but try testing with your event locally (not globally) in the component of interest. There may be duplicate action (CategoryDetails).